# What does mysql -u root -p mean while logging in?

Tags: login, mysql

I am new to using Mysql and I do not understand what does -u and -p imply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are command line options passed to mysql.

`-u` stands for the username and `-p` stands for the password

Whatever comes immediately after `-u` will be the username and after you press <kbd>Return</kbd> you need to enter your password (the password won't be visible and you need to type in your complete password followed by again a <kbd>Return</kbd>, you won't see `*` too in place of the password, it would be completely invisible).

See [the manual page of mysql](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql) for more.

Answer (score 1):

`-u root` says `root` is the user and `-p` will ask for a password.